# Ruby: create a not-inheritable class method

Tags: ruby, oop, inheritance

Let's say I have a class:

```
class Person
  def self.say
    puts "hello"
  end
end
```

And a subclass:

```
  class Woman < Person
  end
```

I want the "say" method to be public method, but I don't want it to be inherited by "Woman" or any other subclass. What's the right way to achieve that?

- I don't want to override the method, as I don't know about future sub classes.
- I know I can use something like `remove_method`, but I would prefer to not inherit the method at all

Comment: That's some strange OOP you're doing there.

Comment: what are you trying to achieve?

Comment: I want to have a static method in the base class, that finds a subclass according to an argument I supply @Gerep

Answer (score 3):

> I want to have a static method in the base class, that finds a subclass according to an argument I supply

Define that static method somewhere else, for example in a module:

```
module Person

  class Base
  end

  class Woman < Base
  end

  def self.create(name)
    case name
    when :woman
      Woman.new
    end
  end

end

Person.create(:woman)          # => #<Person::Woman:0x007fe5040619e0>
Person::Woman.create(:woman)   # => undefined method `create' for Person::Woman:Class
```

Answer (score 1):

I agree that this is a strange requirement. But if you insist, you can create a `inherited` hook for `Person` and manually remove the class methods from the child classes.

```rb
class Person
  def self.say
    puts "Hello"
  end

  def self.inherited(subclass)
    self.methods(false).each do |m|
      subclass.instance_eval { eval("undef :#{m}") }
    end
  end
end

class Woman < Person
end

Person.say   #=> Hello
Woman.say    #=> undefined method `say' for Woman:Class (NoMethodError)
```

Comment: That's something I didn't want to do. (undef/remove_method). I would prefer to not inherit it at all!

Comment: @benams You should go find some other languages :-)

Answer (score 0):

You can check if the class method call is from the parent class or from an inherited class, and then do the appropriate logic for it.

```
class Person 
  def self.say 
    if self.superclass != Person
      puts "Hello"
    else
      puts "Don't say 'hello', make up your own greeting"
    end
  end
end

class Woman < Person 
end

puts Person.say
puts Woman.say
```

This solution passes your two requirements.